# How to pass the date from the calendar to another activity [Android]

Tags: android, calendar

I am having trouble with passing the date from the calendar to another activity. It's not the current date that I wanted to show, it's the date that the user selects on the calendar that I have coded.  
Below are my codes.

```
                            @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    String date_month_year = (String)view.getTag();
                    selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText(new StringBuilder().append("Selected:").append(date_month_year));

                    Intent k = new Intent(Calendar_Event.this, Create_Events.class);
                 startActivity(k);

                    try
                    {
                        Date parsedDate = dateFormatter.parse(date_month_year);
                        Log.d(tag, "Parsed Date: " + parsedDate.toString());
                    }
                    catch(ParseException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } 


                public int getCurrentDayOfMonth()
                    {
                        return currentDayOfMonth;
                    }

                private void setCurrentDayOfMonth(int currentDayOfMonth)
                    {
                        this.currentDayOfMonth = currentDayOfMonth;
                    }
                public void setCurrentWeekDay(int currentWeekDay)
                    {
                        this.currentWeekDay = currentWeekDay;
                    }
                public int getCurrentWeekDay()
                    {
                        return currentWeekDay;
                    }

        }//end GridCellAdapter
```

I trying to pass the date selected onClick to the next activity that this class is linked to. 
 Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Intent.putExtra(String date)` for passing date from one activity to another Activity. Change your Button Click Code as in Calendar_Event.class:

**In Calendar_Event Activity :**

```
//Create new Intent Object, and specify class
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setClass(Calendar_Event.this,Create_Events.class);

intent.putExtra("passdate","Date_var_here");  

Calendar_Event.this.startActivity(intent);
```

**In Create_Events Activity :**

```
//obtain  Intent Object send  from SenderActivity
  Intent intent = this.getIntent();

  /* Obtain String from Intent  */
  if(intent !=null)
  {
     String strdata = intent.getExtras().getString("passdate");
    // DO SOMETHING HERE
  }
  else
  {
    // DO SOMETHING HERE
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to convert calendar variable into long by calling `getTimeInMillis()`

```
/* GetDateActivity.java */

Intent intent = new Intent();

Calendar myDate = Calendar.getInstance();
myDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1970);
myDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
myDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

intent.putExtra("myDateKey", myDate.getTimeInMillis());
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
// Terminate current activity
finish();
```

Then, inside activity which called `startActivityForResult(intent)`, i.e. `MainActivity.java`

```
public static final int REQUEST_DATE_CODE = 777;

...

Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.class, GetDateActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_DATE_CODE);

...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_DATE_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

                Calendar myDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                myDate.setTimeInMillis(extras.getLong("myDateKey"));

                Date date = myDate.getTime();
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy", Locale.getDefault());
                Log.d(tag, "Parsed Date: " + simpleDateFormatter.format(date));
           }
           break;
    }
}
```